# Vimeo: Get download link from API

Tags: c#, .net, vimeo-api

I've Vimeo PRO and I'm trying to get the download link so the end user can download the video source.  However, the lack of documentation makes it really hard to figure that out.

I'm trying [VimeoDotNet](https://github.com/mfilippov/vimeo-dot-net) but I cannot authenticate, I'm doing the following:

```
var client = new VimeoClientFactory().GetVimeoClient(key, secret)
var downloadLink = client.GetVideo(video_id).download;
```

However, the call to GetVideo throws an error saying I have to authenticate first, but I don't see how!

I've also tried with another VimeoClient, but it doesn't seem to implement the download link part.

Can anyone help? Or better yet, share a working example. Thanks.

Comment: Is there an attribute on `client` that you can check to make sure you successfully authenticated?

Comment: No, I think it's not authenticating. It's probably because I have to call something before. Actually the other API has a `Login` method, but not this one. Unfortunately I only have the dll of the other library, not sure where the previous developers download it from. The problem is that big lack of documentation or example in both Vimeo and the libraries.

Comment: You've got the source at least, so you can take a look through that for the workflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 2 days I was finally able to do it, I'll share what I did in case someone needs it.  First, download this library:

https://github.com/saeedafshari/VimeoDotNet3

Open in Visual Studio and compile it. It's pretty simple so it compiled right away.

Then reference that compiled DLL from your project and do the following:

```
var VimeoClient3 = Vimeo.VimeoClient.ReAuthorize(_vimeoAccessToken, 
                   _vimeoAppConsumerKey, _vimeoAppClientSecret);

// videoId is the ID of the video as in the public URL (eg, 123874983)
var result = VimeoClient3.Request("/videos/" + videoId, null, "GET");
if (result == null)
{
    throw new Exception("Video not found.");
}
if (result["download"] == null)
{
    throw new Exception("Download link not available.");
}
foreach (var item in (ArrayList)result["download"])
{
    var downloadLinkInfo = item as Dictionary<string, object>;
    if (downloadLinkInfo == null) continue;

    // For example, get the link for SD quality.
    // As of today, Vimeo was returning an HD quality and a 'mobile' one
    // that is for streaming.
    if (string.Equals((downloadLinkInfo["quality"] as string), "sd", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        return downloadLinkInfo["link"] as string;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps should be noted that in order to get the links for a video, the video poster needs to have a PRO membership level or greater.